# Is there a converse of Landau-Mignotte bound?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb Z$.
Landau-Mignotte bound says that if $f_1$ is a proper factor of $f$, then 
$||f_1||<M\cdot ||f||$ for some bound $M$ which depends on deg of a polynomial.

Is there a converse of Landau-Mignotte bound?

or is there a theorem such that $||f|| < M' ||f_1||$ for some bound $M'$ if $f_1$ is a proper factor of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

If by $\|f\|$ you mean the sum of the absolute values of coefficients of $f$, note that $\|f \| \le \|f_1 \| \| f/f_1\|$, with equality if all coefficients of $f_1$ and $f/f_1$ are nonnegative.  But since $\|f/f_1\|$ can be arbitrarily large, there can't be a bound $\|f \| \le M' \|f_1\|$ that works for all pairs $(f, f_1)$ of given degrees.

Comment: Thank you.! If the norm is an Euclidean norm, is the result same?

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your advice